Why does WLS fail to restore session?
Our clustered WLS 12.2.1.4.0 app is moving to a new environment and we're required to change its session management from "replicated_if_clustered" to "jdbc". Most pages work correctly in the new regime, but one JSF page causes issues - the view restore operation occasionally fails. The underlying error is a unique constraint violation (ORA-00001) on the wl_servlet_sessions table. Errors from further up the stack include BEA-100060 (An unexpected error occurred while retrieving the session for Web application: XXX) and BEA-100087 (The jdbc session data for session id: XXX has been modified by another server in the cluster.)
We have a filter in place to catch serialization errors, and it tells us the session for this page is especially large - over 10 Mbytes is common, sometimes three times that size. That is the only thing we've been able to find that distinguishes this troublesome JSF page.
Our speculation is that the size of the session causes the problem. Changing the underlying code to reduce the session size is not an option at present. We're unable to find much documentation (or even blogs) that are relevant. (The best we've found is Oracle Support doc 2439083.1, which basically tells us to configure it correctly.)
We assumed that restoring the session data is a synchronous operation, but perhaps that isn't the case. If it were synchronous, it seems that a large session might slow things down but wouldn't cause a failure.
My questions are: Has anyone experienced a similar issue with restoring sessions using JDBC session serialization in WLS? Are we correct in our speculation that the large session size is the problem?
